# Completely new to ubuntu and I can't get it to boot

Tags: nvidia

I installed it from a USB stick alongside windows vista on a gateway computer. And I asked reddit to help I was able to get it to boot but the screen was weird and it would only boot if put into recovery mode and the booted into Ubuntu. I have a screen shot of what me and the guy on Reddit did but I can't add it due to low rep if u need it you can msg my discord--->satan#9939